# List view like Slot machine in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have 5 list view on the page. Every list view has some list of texts. Users scroll them to choice one.

The problem is: **How can I detect that an item is centered the list view to select it as the selected item, like a slot machine.**

There is just an Item_Appearing event that define the next appeared item in the list not the centered item.

Comment: Pickers do that, at least they do on iOS. Not an Android user so I’m not sure.

Comment: Adding more than 1 ListView on the same page is not a good practice to begin with what exactly are you trying to achieve here

Comment: @G.hakim suppose there is just one list view, so what should I do?

Comment: To be very honest your requirement sounds like a picker control

Comment: @G.hakim Yes you're right if there is one list view. But I want to implement an Slot machine, so picker control wont help me

Comment: Like this? https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV-L2ul67gAhUNfisKHS1zDa8QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vegasnews.com%2F25558%2Fjackpot-slots-converts-iphone-to-slot-machine-with-handle.html&psig=AOvVaw20wSc0RCZ2TEU7SQM_I128&ust=1549785585261926

Comment: @G.hakim yes, or this https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fimage.shutterstock.com%2Fz%2Fstock-photo-three-cherries-in-a-row-on-slot-machine-wheels-or-dials-to-illustrate-big-jackpot-winnings-315885758.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsocieteitquintessence.nl%2Fslot-machine-cherry-images%2F&docid=jKHqE1mVS0Z1YM&tbnid=V3ZReO6K9M4dSM%3A&vet=12ahUKEwjg2qDGv4zgAhXC1qQKHT_fDJk4yAEQMygdMB16BAgBEB4..i&w=1500&h=973&bih=626&biw=1366&q=slot%20machine%20psd&ved=2ahUKEwjg2qDGv4zgAhXC1qQKHT_fDJk4yAEQMygdMB16BAgBEB4&iact=mrc&uact=8

Answer (score 0):

This kind of features aren't really the forte of Forms so creating a custom control is probably your best option. If you aren't interested in doing that then I would tap into two things on the listview.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemappearing?view=xamarin-forms

Detect when items are appearing on the list, this way you can figure out what item is closest to the center. Then use [ScrollTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms) method to automatically [center the item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrolltoposition?view=xamarin-forms). The biggest issue with this approach I see is detecting when the user has ended the scrolling as you don't want to center the item while the user is still scrolling. If this is like slot machine where the user "pulls the handle" and the listviews scroll automatically you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I want to scroll to the next item is appearing and select it, when the user scroll the list up or down. So your solution make always scrolling to the end or start.

Comment: You can specify the scrollTo position.